# concatinate pandas dataframe to multiindex

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like this

```
df1=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(3,3)),columns=list('ABC'))
df1.index.name="ID1"


df2=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(3,3)),columns=list('ABC'))
df2.index.name="ID2"
```

so,How can I concatinate like below,this dataframe have multiindex.

```
        A  B  C 
ID1 0   7  5  7
    1   6  3  8
    2   6  5  4
ID2 0   3  9  7
    1   8  7  5
    2   3  9  9
```

I have tried 'pd.concat([df1,df2])' but multiindex hasnt created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concat is correct

```
pd.concat([df1,df2], keys=['id1', 'id2'])
```